# convert object to json data from sql

Tags: javascript, json, symfony, prepared-statement

I want to convert data object to json form, this is my code in symfony,

```
 $connection = $em->getConnection();
    $statement = $connection->prepare("select * from contact where id_user=$id");
    $statement->execute();
    $contacts = $statement->fetchAll();
```

and in rendering object, I do this,

```
return $this->render('...index.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'errors' => $form->getErrors(), 'contacts'=>json_encode($contacts)));
```

but this does not work, any help please

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$contacts= json_encode($contacts);
$Response = new Response(
  '...myTemplate.html.twig',
  ['form' => $form->createView()],
  ['errors' => $form->getErrors()],
  ['contacts' => $contacts]
);
$Response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $oResponse;
```

Don't forget to use:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
```

Or you can use the JsonResponse Class. Here's the documentation:
[symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/components/http_foundation/introduction.html)